# Execute DDL/SQL files with SqlAlchemy and get good error messages

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

Consider a simple SQL file like this:

dummy.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS blah;

CREATE TABLE blah AS
SELECT * 
FROM blahblah2;
```

I can run it from the command line and get a nice error message:

```
$ mysql -u ... -h ... ... < /tmp/dummy.sql 
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 3: Table 'yourdb.blahblah2' doesn't exist
```

Or I can run it from SQL Alchemy like this:

```
import sqlalchemy

ddl_sql = open("/tmp/dummy.sql").read()

connect_string = "mysql+mysqldb://.../"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connect_string)

engine.execute(ddl_sql)
```

When I run it from SQL Alchemy I get a giant stack trace with the following underlying error:

```
"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"
```

How can I get the "real error" out of SQL Alchemy?

(someone asked for the traceback, so here it is)

```
 File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 507, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 252, in execute
    self._warning_check()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 148, in _warning_check
    warnings = db.show_warnings()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 381, in show_warnings
    self.query("SHOW WARNINGS")
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    engine.execute(ddl_sql)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2075, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 942, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1104, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 507, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 252, in execute
    self._warning_check()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 148, in _warning_check
    warnings = db.show_warnings()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 381, in show_warnings
    self.query("SHOW WARNINGS")
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") [SQL: 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_junk_delete;\n\nCREATE TABLE TMP_junk_delete AS\nSELECT * \nFROM goals;\n\nDROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_junk_delete;\n\nCREATE TABLE TMP_junk_delete AS\nSELECT * \nFROM goals;\n\nDROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_junk_delete;\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: Do you get that error if you run a correct SQL file too? (i.e.: are you sure that `Commands out of sync...` is actually indicating an SQL error further down the stack?)

Comment: I suspect that if you submitted these command separately, it would work, i.e. you have two DDL commands that you are submitting as one. Have you considered parsing the file, command-by-command, and submitting them in sequence?

Comment: @NiayeshIsky : No error with correct file. Files that generate warnings have the same problem as those that generate errors. (e.g. DROP IF TABLE EXISTS for table that does not exist)

Comment: @djkern : Yes, the problem does not manifest for single-statement SQL files but parsing them is challenging (given the full complexity of the SQL grammar). There are other hacks which are less work: I could shell out to the mysql command line and then parse the errors in generates.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: I added the traceback.

Comment: Here's the issue you're facing: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/70, though there's not much of a solution there. If you were [using a raw connection and cursor](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets), you could then call `cur.nextset()` to inspect the actual error that happened before executing `SHOW WARNINGS`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä : For my specific use-case I seem to have worked around the problem by adding these lines:

from MySQLdb.cursors import BaseCursor

BaseCursor._defer_warnings = True

I'm still working on getting access to the exception data but I can probably get at it through the logging infrastructure or something like that. SQL Alchemy logs the exception and then swallows it.